# what are some online Simulators for Photographic equipments?

Tags: lens, body, learning, photography-basics

What are some **online simulators for equipments like camera, lens, etc**?
I have been asking this question a few times and searched about it and found a few things. 
I present it in Q&A format so that others can add their answers as well. Put in the answers with appropriate links.

Comprehensively this might be helpful for beginners in understanding and learning.

Comment: See also [How can I visualize or simulate the effect of different focal lengths?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9133/how-can-i-visualize-or-simulate-the-effect-of-different-focal-lengths). If we want to make this question not a duplicate, answers should focus on simulators which cover _other_ aspects.

Comment: @mattdm The question you pointed just focuses on "focal length". This question is about additionally other aspects like camera's working including lens too.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Camera Simulator:**

[**Camerasim**](http://camerasim.com/) - A simulator which allows you to experiment all modes and with different ligthing, focal length and subject distance by varying Shutter Speed, Aperture and ISO.

**Lens Simulator:**

[**NIKKOR Lens Simulator**](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/simulator/) - A simulator for lens that allows you to experiment various focal length lenses on Full frame and crop sensors.

Answer (score 3):

**Matching Simulation:**

[MicroFourThirds Matching Simulation](http://www.four-thirds.org/en/special/matching.html) - To simulate how the lenses look like on the different cameras.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this online Camera Simulator**

This simulator shows the reciprocal relationship between aperture and exposure time, the light metre, ISO, depth of field, and motion blur using a realistic scene in an intuitive way. (I like it.)

[kamerasimulator.se](http://www.kamerasimulator.se/eng/?page_id=2)